# What is an "above-market dividend yield"?

Tags: investing

I know a dividend yield is how much in dividends you get back, but what does the "above market" portion of that term mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without context, "market" is generally defined by the average of an index.  The average dividend yield of the S&P 500 is 2.2%, "above market" would be a yield above that.  You could also average the yields of an industry and compare that way.